# File missing issue while running mongodb in windows 8.1

Tags: mongodb

I installed the mongodb and created a new directory in C drive to store db data to that directory. After initialising a new directory, i run the below command to start the mongodb.

> "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath c:\data\db

But i am getting the error, "api-ms-win-crt-runtime" is missing from your computer.I have attached the image below.

[image: Error image]

Please tell me, what should i need to do to fix this?

Comment: I am also getting the same

Comment: This is the issue with the windows 32 bit operating system!!!

Comment: i have 64 bit os.